# Why can't I change UIView Class of root View of a ViewController

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, iboutlet

If I start an Xcode program with a single view template, it will default to a VC and a View already setup as an IBOutlet in that VC so that I can access it using `self.view` in my View Controller.

Now, if I wanted to have a custom UIView (called NewView), I can add a UIView class file (`.h`/`.m`) in my project. Now my initial thought would then to go to the root "UIview" in storyboard and change its class to "NewView".

Assuming I have a public property in NewView called "myProperty", I should be able to access it from my VC using `self.view.myProperty`. That is not the case!

Are we saying that the only way to subclass a UIView is to add a UIView object in SB that is below the root UIView and then create an IBOutlet from the VC to that UIView? So what it then the use of that root UIView if I cannot use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a matter of not being able to subclass `UIView` (as you have seen already), it's a matter of the compiler recognizing your subclass.  `self.view` is declared as a pointer to a `UIView` object, not of your subclass, so you have to do a little extra work to access it's properties; namely: casting.  To access "myProperty", use `[(NewView*)self.view myProperty];`.  Simple as that.

You have to cast as a sort of promise to the compiler that literally states "`self.view` has the class `NewView`, not what you think it is, so recognize it as such."

As a side note, I would also make sure that the class of the root view in the XIB is set appropriately (meaning, it needs to be of class `NewView`, else when you try to message it, your cast will fail and return a `UIView` object, which does not respond to `-myProperty`, thus throwing a generic exception).

Comment: So within MVC model:UIVC has a "view" prop of class UIView and when we load the project,an automatic outlet is created for that "view" prop in the UIVC to point to the UIView class. When I change the class of UIView (subclass) to NewView, in SB; the "view" outlet is updated in SB so that it is now pointing to NewView class. But nothing happens on the code side to tell UIVC that the "view" outlet it is pointing to is a NewView class now. And that is why self.view would still work since "view" is a prop NewView inherits from UIView but, the code does not recognize any of the new prop of NewView?

Comment: What does "not recognize" mean?  Does it compile or not?

Comment: Sorry. Just to be clear, casting as you mentioned solved the problem. I was commenting above to further understanding. What I meant is that, without the cast; when writing code, xCode does not "autocomplete" for example the property names. But equally if I try to build, I get an error - eventhough I have #include it "NewView.h" in the UIVC class. That is the expected behavior, correct?

Comment: Well, Xcode's autocomplete depends on CLANG's awesome error returning mechanism for it's completions, and because self.view points to a UIView object, not your subclass, it's as though you were referencing a UIView if you don't use a cast.